# issue with OOP Class Definitions

Tags: c++, oop, class

I work for my homework in C++ and i have some problems with multiply definitions.

My graph class ;

```
 class Graph{

     private:
          string name;                          //Graph name
          fstream* graphFile;                   //Graph's file

  protected:
    string opBuf;                         //Operations buffer
          int containsNode(string);             //Query if a node is present    
          Node* nodes;                          //Nodes in the graph
          int nofNodes;                         //Number of nodes in the graph

  public:
          static int nOfGraphs;                 //Number of graphs produced

          Graph();                              //Constructors and destructor
          Graph(int);
          Graph(string);
          Graph(const Graph &);
          ~Graph();

          string getGraphName();                //Get graph name
          bool addNode(string);                 //add a node to the graph
          bool deleteNode(string);              //delete a node from the graph
          bool addEdge(string,string);          //add an edge to the graph
          bool deleteEdge(string,string);       //delete an edge from the graph
          void intersect(const Graph&);         //intersect the graph with the <par>
          void unite(const Graph&);             //intersect the graph with the <par>
          string toString();                    //get string representation of the graph
       void acceptTraverse(BreadthFirst*);
    void acceptTraverse(DepthFirst *);


};
```

and my traversal class;

```
 class Traversal {
public:
 string *visitedNodes;

 virtual string traverse (const Graph & );
};

class BreadthFirst  : public Traversal {
public :
 BreadthFirst();
 string traverse();
};

class DepthFirst : public Traversal {
public :
 DepthFirst();
 string traverse();
};
```

My problem is in traversal class , i need to declare Graph class at the same time , in graph class i need traversal class to declare.

I have big problems with declerations :) Could you please help me ?

Comment: I just wanted to say, that  you really do not need to comment code this way. Every line of code should be self-explanatory, and I think it really is in your case, so you really do not need to copy the information. The things you should comment instead are decisions, e.g. you used node object based graph implementation (instead of edge object or edge matrix based).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No you don't need the definition of the classes. You just need to give the hint to the compiler that `Graph` and `Traversal` are classes. So use [forward declartion](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/misc-technical-issues.html#faq-39.11) like `class BreadthFirst;` in the definition of `Graph` (i..e just above class Graph{....}). Similarly use `class Graph;` before the definition of  Traversal class.

Answer (score 2):

Forward declaring would help, look into just doing acceptTraverse(Traversal*), the [Visitor Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visitor_pattern) is something that might help you.

Answer (score 1):

if i understood truely, i tried this ;

in **graph class** , before graph class declerations i added

```
class BreadthFirst;
class DepthFirst;
```

and in **traversal.cpp** file i used this ;

```
#include "Graph.h"
#include "Traversal.h"
```

With this, lots of problems solved but for now ;

> Error    8    error LNK2001:
>   unresolved external symbol "public:
>   virtual class
>   std::basic_string,class
>   std::allocator > __thiscall
>   Traversal::traverse(class Graph const
>   &)"
>   (?traverse@Traversal@@UAE?AV?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@ABVGraph@@@Z)
>   &  nbsp; c:\Users\oben
>   isik\documents\visual studio
>   2010\Projects\hw2\hw2\main.obj
>
> Error    9    error LNK1120: 1
>   unresolved externals    c:\users\oben
>   isik\documents\visual studio
>   2010\Projects\hw2\Debug\hw2.exe    1

What can i do now ?

Answer (score 0):

pre declare your class before one of them,  eg, in the Traversal header file, before the traversal class you need a statement

class Graph;

then it will know a Graph class will exist at some point